# How to enable or disable a asp button on dropdown selection value using Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, dom-events

I have  asp dropdown and button, I want to make the button always disable when dropdown selected value is index 0 and enable when some other value is selected.

My code, but it is not working:

```
function checkSelect()
{
if (document.getElementById('ddlSte').value == 'Select One')
   document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = true;
else
   document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = false;
}
```

controls:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSte" runat="server" Width="162px" onchange='checkSelect(this);'>
             </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    
 <asp:Button ID="StGoBtn" CssClass="buttnStyle" runat="server" Text="GO>>"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Show us the html you have for dropdown and button

Comment: @Adil You can read my question that i am using asp dropdown and button

Comment: @son code seems fine, post the html code for dropdown, button and calling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<%=ddlSte.ClientID %>` and `<%=StGoBtn.ClientID %>` in your code.

```
function checkSelect()
{
   if (document.getElementById('<%=ddlSte.ClientID %>').value == 'Select One')
       document.getElementById('<%=StGoBtn.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
   else
       document.getElementById('<%=StGoBtn.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
}
```

The Id of control get changed If you use `msterpag` or `user control` so you need to use ClientID to get the actual IP

More detail about client ID
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature

Comment: little more specific?

Comment: @son it is there in my answer. You can use that.

Comment: @sekhar It worked.Thanks.One more help can you tell me how to call this function on page load event?

Answer (score 2):

Controls in Asp.NET have not the same ID as you have declared in your code.

First approach to get your solution working is to declare your `DownDropList` and your `Button` with the attribute `ClientIDMode` to `Static`. This way, rendered ID will be the same you declared in your code.

Best approach, is to use the @Șhȇkhaṝ proposal. You can, for example, define the `onchange` attribute as:

```
onchange='checkSelect(<%=ddlSte.ClientID %>, <%=StGoBtn.ClientID %>);'
```

And then redefine your `checkSelect` function as:

```
function checkSelect(ddlID, buttonID) { ... }
```

Comment: I recommend change ClientIDMode to Static to make JavaScript code clean and readable.

Comment: Agree is you are going to use a lot of jQuery, but in such cases I prefer non using ASP controls, but regular HTML tags (if no server side actions are required).

Answer (score 1):

I got this result by using jquery.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=StGoBtn.ClientID%>").hide();
    $("#<%=ddlSte.ClientID%>").change(function () {

        if ($("#<%=ddlSte.ClientID%>").val() == "Select One") {
            $("#<%=StGoBtn.ClientID%>").hide();               
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=StGoBtn.ClientID%>").show();

        }

    });

});
</script>
```

**Note:**

1.Inorder to work with jquery we need to add below url at head section of your html page

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

2.The DropDown Default value(like "***Select One***") must be the value which you compare the value in jquery code i.e;if ($("#<%=ddlSte.ClientID%>").val() == "***Select One***")

3.You no need to add  a function in your dropdown html.i.e; simply you can write it as show below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSte" runat="server" Width="162px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: He is not asking about using jQuery, and your approach is not going to work since IDs are not statics.

Comment: why downvoted?i dont know jquery resolves lot of issues

Comment: Hello dude.Just check out jquery.com .it has lot of advantages when compare to javascript.i just give the way to solve the problem in another way.because of downvoted others may think its wrong.Answering a question not only searcihng for solution but also give the guidance which is best.Please check it once.It may effect others.

Comment: Again, your approach is not going to work since IDs are not static. See @Șhȇkhaṝ reply.

Comment: check once.because of "});" its not worked.now it works

Comment: Sorry dude i understand your problem.i changed my code.please check it.if any errors are there.i will change.once again sorry.

Comment: Why any one downvote any answer because its a help,may or may not work.Nothing wrong in suggesting some1.

Comment: downvote is a warning symbol when you are ready to post anything on site.Stackoverflow maintain some standards of their Questions and Answers.Inorder to skip useless answers they add downvoted app.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

In ASPX

```
   <div>  
    <select id="ddlSte" onchange="test();">
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select> 
   </div>
```

In JavaScript

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (document.getElementById('ddlSte').value == '0')
            document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = true;
        else
            document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = false;
    });
    function test() {

        if (document.getElementById('ddlSte').value == '0')
            document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = true;
        else
            document.getElementById('StGoBtn').disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I dont want to use autopostback because is refreshes the page

Comment: This approach must not cause autopostback.